# How to custom colors of a seaboard's heat map?

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, heatmap

I am using heatmap because of the final structure, not the color gamut itself.

I show a small example below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pdb import set_trace as bp

dic_data = {'x':    [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5],
            'y':    [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
            'note': [1, 4, 9, 16, 20, 16, 9, 10, 4, 14, 16, 16]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic_data)

df_p  = df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['note'].count().reset_index()
df_p  = df_p.pivot_table('note', 'y', 'x', fill_value = 0).sort_index(level = 0, ascending = False)

dic_parse = {'y': {1: 'Very low',
                   2: 'Low',
                   3: 'Normal',
                   4: 'High'},
             'x': {1: 'VL',
                   2: 'L',
                   3: 'N',
                   4: 'H',
                   5: 'VH'}}

xticklabels = [dic_parse['x'][e] for e in df_p.keys().tolist()]
yticklabels = [dic_parse['y'][e] for e in df_p.index.tolist()]


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (9, 6))
sns.heatmap(df_p, annot = True, fmt = 'd', linewidths = .5, cbar = False, cmap = 'Greens',
            annot_kws = {'size': 50}, xticklabels = xticklabels, yticklabels = yticklabels)

ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize = 20)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize = 20)
ax.set_ylim([df_p.size / len(df_p.columns), 0])
plt.show()
```

This should be the result of executing this code:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to choose what color appears in each cell, so that the lower left triangle is red (from (N-Very low) and (VL-Normal) to below), the upper right triangle is green (from (N-High) and (VH-Low) to above) and the central area is yellow.

This is my desire result:

[image]

I don't know if this is possible with heatmap or with another function.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Comment: You will need a matrix of values that correspond to the colors. Then you can annotate the heatmap as shown in https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that I'm not understanding the solution... What I want is to "unlink" the data shown in the heatmap from the corresponding colors, and I can't find where something similar is done in the link that you have given me.

Comment: No, sure. It's rather that you have to draw a completely different heatmap first, namely one with, say, zeros on the lower part, ones on the diagonal, twos on the upper part. The link will then help you to annotate that heatmap.

Comment: Ups, now I understand you. I'll try some code and tell you later.